# Exporting a UV Mesh from an Existing Model

Tags: mesh, uv, export, unreal-engine

Fairly new to Blender so I have a straightforward question.

I have created a fern which I will be exporting into Unreal Engine. I created the fern texture inside of blender using 2 images - one for each leaf and one for the end leaf (end cap onto an array).

I am now at the point where I am moving my model across and I need both the mesh and UV map. The mesh is simple enough (exporting as fbx) but is there a way to export the texture currently on my model? If not, what is the best way forward?

On a side note, unwrapping the mesh turns the entire fern white (removing the texture?).

Images below and I can upload the file if needed.

[image: The fern fully rendered and ready for export. Note the UV editor being empty.]

[image: Texture on mesh, this needs to be exported.]

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

UV coordinates will be exported with most 3D formats like FBX, or OBJ so you do not need to worry about this usually. You will only need to recreate the materials for the objects in the different rendering environment. You will need to copy the actual texture files together with the exported model and then point the new materials to the texture files while creating them in Unreal Engine.

Comment: You sent this while I was writing my own answer!

I ended up basically doing what you suggested. The UV Co-ordinates exported perfectly but not the actual texture itself. I was hoping that I could move exactly what I was seeing on my screen to UE but that does not seem possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An update from my side:

I don't believe it is possible to export the complete texture of the fern however when moving it to Unreal 4 I noticed a 2 things:

1. The imported mesh knew it was supposed to have several materials assigned to it
2. UE4's material editor can complete similar functions to Blender's in different ways

So I have imported the mesh into UE4 and recreated the materials as best I could. I then used the mesh material slots to properly assign the materials.

[image]

To all those who come across this post, I recommend texturing your items in Blender but not in great detail. This will create the material slots and give a good representation of what your design will look like. Do all the finishing touches in UE4 and you won't end up wasting a bunch of time like me.

**(ノಥ,_｣ಥ)ノ彡┻━┻**

Cheers.